# I want to see if a file is opened with gedit. Is it possible?

Tags: files, gedit

There is a command-line option to see what files are open with gedit?
If I open two files in gedit (file1 and file2) and in terminal I use the command:

```
ps ax | grep-v grep | grep gedit
```

I get only the first file opened. (5944 pts/0    S+     0:01 gedit  /home/file1)

Using this command I do not see that file2 is also open in gedit. It is another way?

Comment: I think that's an interesting question. On my system even `lsof` doesn't know about any open files related to `gedit` even if `strace` shows they *have* been opened.

Comment: I found a solution to remotely edit a file with gedit as root. And this is the only problem, to know when the edited file was closed...

Comment: Note: Use `ps -C gedit` to search for an known app and avoid to double grep.

Comment: May I ask why you need to know, whether the file is open in gedit or which file is open in gedit? There might be another solution for the underlying problem.

Comment: `code`ps -C gedit
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 5964 tty1     00:00:01 gedit
`/code` Where is informations about file1 and file2 ?

Comment: Why I need to know? I create an action for nautilus only for sftp files. This action launch an script that connect by ssh with "expect", copy file into tmp folder with 777 permissions, edit with gedit and WHEN this file is closed copy to old location and restore permissions... Is for edit remote files as root.

Comment: I can use the SciTE editor . But I'm only interested in gedit.

Comment: @geoscorilo: does using `gedit --standalone` help you? It will start a new process of gedit even if gedit is already running, and it prevents newly opened documents from being opened by that process. You could wait for this process to exit. Of course, the user shouldn't open tabs of her own, but that's probably clear.

Comment: @ Timo Kluck, in man gedit not exists option "-- standalone". I tried with - new-window but it still does not recognize open files ...

Answer (score 3):

gedit doesn't keep the file open while you are editing it, so I'm not sure you can.
You could probably write a gedit plugin that could tell you, but let's ignore that option for now.

Going on the comments above, you are really just wanting a way to edit a file, and know when it's been closed. @TimoKluck suggests `--standalone`, but I think you probably want `--wait` instead.

You can also achieve the same thing through gedit's D-Bus API. When you open a file, it gives you a cookie, which you can then wait on.